# how to pass query items in NSURL get request?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Below is the string that I need to create as a url for GET request. I am always getting nil in NSURL.
Can anyone help me ?

```
  http://example.com/webexternal1/api/Values/sendorder?orderlist={code:"122|155",rate:"60|5",qty:"5|5"}&tab=N2

//strParams = {code:122|155,rate:60|5,qty:5|5}&tab=N2

    dataUrl = [@"http://example.com/webexternal1/api/Values/sendorder?orderlist=" stringByAppendingString:strParams];
            urlComponants = [[NSURLComponents alloc]initWithString:dataUrl];
            NSURL *url = urlComponants.URL;
```

Comment: What's the exact value of `strParams`?

Comment: strParams = {code:122|155,rate:60|5,qty:5|5}&tab=N2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try url encoding the strParams.

```
NSString* strParams = [@"{code:122|155,rate:60|5,qty:5|5}&tab=N2" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: This correct. But stringBy... is deprecated. Use the newer call.

Comment: Worked Thanks , This is the new method [strParams stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLHostAllowedCharacterSet]]